# patching a method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, testing, monkeypatching

How do you patch a method in Ruby as you do in Python via @patch decorator?

Whatever I've so far seen on Ruby's monkey patching falls into 'overloading' rather than patching.
What I need now, is patch curb's curl method to return some expected results instead of actually looking up things. How do I do that?
Import and overload curl.get()?

Is there even a same approach or should I start thinking somehow different?

Comment: Are you using a testing framework like RSpec or Minitest?

Comment: I suggest reading the docs for [RSpec Mocks](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs).